# Why MapReduce processing Avro files is slower than processing flat files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, avro

Why MapReduce processing Avro files is slower than processing flat files?

I expected that processing Avro files would be a lot faster than processing flat files, but my assumption is wrong.

Avro output will have the schema attached with the results so I thought that's why it is slow as it would have to write column name + data into HDFS. But that is not the case either as I tried disabling writing to HDFS but the performance didn't improve.

When I removed most of the Avro Class such as AvroKey, AvroValue and I could see the performace improve.

Is this expected or something else is wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How large is your input that you are processing? Also, can you paste in your avro schema? And finally what framework/language are you using to process the data in Hadoop?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I'm testing on data with variations in size: 2GB, 10Gb, 25GB, 50GB, 70GB & 100GB. I have a schema for input and another for output. Unfortunately, I don't have the schema with me but I'll post it once I get a hold of it. The input schema has around 50 columns (Record type with mix of string, long and double types) and the output schema has around 10 columns (Record type with mix of string, long and double types). I'm using Cloudera's Hadoop and the MapReduce is written in Java.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "processing flat files". Basically Avro have to de-serialize the whole object and construct the object. It can be slower than carefully parsing easily parse-able text files. A good way to understand your performance profiles and visualize your hotspots could be using flamegraphs. See https://github.com/cykl/hprof2flamegraph for example (disclaimer I'm the author). Lot of other parameters could explain what you observe, the only way to know is to profile and understand what you are doing.